# Extra term in E.O.M. for Nambu-Goto action with general targetspace metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, action, variational-calculus

Strangely I haven't found a derivation of the E.O.M. of a string in an arbitrary background metric $G_{\mu \nu}$ from the Nambu-Goto action. (Many places present it for the Polyakov action.) Upon attempting to derive it for myself, however, I find there is an extra term that shouldn't be there.

The Nambu-Goto action is
$$
S_{NG} = -T \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{-h}
$$
where
$$
h_{ab} := G_{\alpha \beta}(X) \partial_a X^\alpha \partial_b X^\beta.
$$
The Euler-Lagrange equation is
$$
0 = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{ \partial X^\mu} - \partial_c \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{ \partial \partial_c X^\mu}.
$$
Using
$$
\delta \sqrt{-h} = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-h} h^{ab} \delta h_{ab}
$$
we get
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{ \partial X^\mu} = -\frac{T}{2}\sqrt{-h} h^{ab} (\partial_\mu G_{\alpha \beta}) \partial_a X^\alpha \partial_b X^\beta
$$
for the first term in the Euler-Lagrange equation. For the second term, we get
$$
\partial_c \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{ \partial \partial_c X^\mu} = -T \partial_c(\sqrt{-h} h^{ac} G_{\alpha \mu} \partial_a X^\alpha).
$$
Here we recognize the $\partial_c \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{ \partial \partial_c X^\mu}$ term as the rightful equation of motion, derivable from the Polyakov action. However, the other term, $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{ \partial X^\mu}$, is puzzling me. Shouldn't it be $0$?

Comment: Hint: The correct eom involves spacetime Christoffel symbols ..

Comment: So why don't they appear in the Polyakov e.o.m.?

Comment: they do .. what do you find if you trust your calculation when you go through it carefully?